# New tag for text reuse?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Many questions ask essentially about reusing pieces of text in multiple places in a document. The question titles don't always reflect this commonality.
Answers call for external files, boxes, redefined macros, writing to the aux file, ...

Should there be a tag for this? Perhaps `reuse`?

I have asked or answered several such questions. Here are a few:

- [Put from external file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151367/put-from-external-file/151677#151677)
- [Viva preparation document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150858/viva-preparation-document/151707#151707)
- [How to use a string in an auxiliary file to update the header?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151373/how-to-use-a-string-in-an-auxiliary-file-to-update-the-header/151377#151377)
- [list of occurences of references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60986/list-of-occurences-of-references)

I have enough reputation to create this tag, but given the warnings in help about doing so with care, want opinions before I do.

Comment: this does seem useful, but i wouldn't like to see it applied to such things as the toc or various "lists of", or marks used for running heads, even though those are distinctly examples of reuse.

Comment: This seems like a pretty good idea, but perhaps we should make it something more descriptive.  Perhaps `content-replication`?  `reuse` seems too vague.

Comment: another tag, [reuse-content], appeared on [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130294/filecontents-and-newenvironment-issue}). this was changed to [content-replication], which was just added as a new tag.  i tried to propose the [reuse-content] as a synonym, but was not allowed to.  will someone else, who has the necessary privilege, please do so.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I tagged a question with [reuse-content] and suggested it as a synonym for [content-replication]. The SE documentation suggests that several users of the tag have to approve the synonym. But there aren't many users, so it will probably live in limbo, unless a moderator addresses the question.